# getting xml update response before xml get response in serverside dhtmlxScheduler

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am trying to load events from a server into a dhtmlxScheduler instance. For now, I've exactly modeled the tutorials on dhtmlx's site. I am able to successfully create the scheduler and handle all javascript events and I can load a text xml doc into the scheduler to grab some test events. But, when I try to connect to the a test MySQL table, the response xml contains an xml update response before displaying the xml server response. I am not sure where this xml update is coming from. And, due to this xml update response, my actual xml cannot be parsed correctly because there are basically two root xml tags...

NOTE: I am able to load data from the same server and database for dhtmlxgrid components as well as update.

My Code:

scheduler instance:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Production Scheduler</title>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="../bms/dhtmlxScheduler_v4.4.0/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.css">
<script src="../bms/dhtmlxScheduler_v4.4.0/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.js">
</script>
<script>
  function doOnLoad(){
    var dp;
    scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
    scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(),"month");
    scheduler.load("production_manager_sched_GET.php");
    //dp=new dataProcessor("production_manager_sched_UPDATE.php");
    //dp.init(scheduler);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="doOnLoad()">
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:1800px; height:950px; margin: auto;'>
  <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
    <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
  </div>
<div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
<div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>      
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

My Server-side Script:

```
<?php
  include("inc.php");
  include("../bms/dhtmlxScheduler_v4.4.0/codebase/connector/db_mysqli.php");
  include("../bms/dhtmlxScheduler_v4.4.0/codebase/connector/scheduler_connector.php");
  $res=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
  $conn=new schedulerConnector($res,'MySQLi');
  $conn->render_table("events2","id","start_date,end_date,text");
?>
```

My XML Response (as an alert):

[image: xml response shows xml update response first]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code looks suspicious, I'd suggest checking the contents of **inc.php** you're including, maybe there is some extra code

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, after further testing, I was able to confirm successfully that it will work outside of the API login. But, as soon as I move it in the API (after session start), the extra response starts.